# Set excel cell value2 property takes lot of time

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have excel template file to export data to excel using Interop.Excel. In the template file I have several **data validations to several columns**. I am writing excel value for each cell in a loop

```
Excel.Range headerDataRange;
headerDataRange.Value2 = value;
```

I did a performance analysis to my method. In that it shows this takes lot of time. But when I am not using my template file it takes only few seconds. I think due to those data validations and the formulas in cell is costly.

Can any body suggest a good way to do this.

Comment: I'm not familiar using excel com with templates. but can you load the file and make your edits and then load the validation later after a batch of edits are done?

Comment: validations are placed in the excel template it self

Comment: I don' think there's a way apart of doing this @payo's way!

Comment: @udaya726 Yes, I'm saying, can you delay that? It would seem from your description that this is a slowdown. So, make your edits free of validation, then use the template to validate the whole file. Perhaps use a temp file until edits are validated.

Comment: how many times are you actually looping? It may be the loops that slow  everything down.. You know Range is a 2d array and copying ranges CAN easily be done without looping